# How would you use a case to convert an enum to a string in C?

Tags: c, enums, case

How would I go about making an enum into a string using a case such as 
enum {Ace,....King} face;
to a case that would convert it to say "Ace" rather than a 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char const* faceToString(face f)
{
   switch (f)
   {
       case Ace:
          return "Ace";
       case Two:
          return "Two";

       ...

       case King:
          return "King"
   }
}
```